# How can I find latest row (date and time) in 1 to many relation using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: users(**user_id**, country) and message(**time_date**, currency, amount_sold, *message_user_FK*). The tables are in a 1:Many relationship i.e each user can have multiple messages. I would like to find the latest message for every country. I have the following query but it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

```
  SELECT u.country, s.date_time 
  FROM users u 
  JOIN message s ON u.user_id = s.message_user_FK
  JOIN(
  SELECT message_user_FK ,MAX(date_time) date_time 
  FROM message 
  GROUP BY message_user_FK 
  ) s1
  ON(s.message_user_FK = s1.message_user_FK  AND s.date_time =   s1.date_time );
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03858/20

Comment: How does it not work?  Do you want the latest message or the latest message time?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it outputs all the rows. I would like the country name together with the latest date_time. date_time is of type DateTime in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the country with the latest date time, use a simple query . . . `join` and `group by`:

```
SELECT u.country, MAX(s.date_time)
FROM users u JOIN
     message m
     ON u.user_id = m.message_user_FK
GROUP BY u.country;
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this?

```
SELECT u.country ,MAX(m.date_time) date_time 
FROM users u
     JOIN message m on u.user_id = m.message_user_FK
GROUP BY u.country
```

You subquery was close -- you were just grouping by the incorrect field.  This would do the same.

---

- [Your updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03858/21)